# C# - Comparing two CSV Files and giving an output

Tags: c#, csv

Need a bit of help, I have two sources of information and the information is exported to two different CSV file's by different programs. They are supposed to include the same information, however this is what needs to be checked.

Therefore what I would like to do is as follows:

- Take the information from the two files.
- Compare
- Output any differences and which file the difference was in. (e.g File A Contained this, but File B did not and vice versa).

The files are 200,000 odd rows so will need to be as effective as possible.

Tried doing this with Excel however has proved to be too complicated and I'm really struggling to find a way programatically.

Comment: It would help if you were more specific about the differences you expect to find - differences in data, or in format as well? Same number of lines? etc...

Comment: Is ordering meant to be the same in both files? The solution differs considerably depending on whether it does or not.

Comment: OK, sorry. 

The differences should be in data, there is one column of ID's and one column of a version.

There are a different number of lines. The format is the same, e.g ID in first column with X number of rows, and Version in second column with the same amount of rows.

The ordering wont be the same, a row in file A won't be the same in file B or though it could be.

An easy way to describe what needs to be done would probably be a list of names, however they are not ordered and just put into the sheet. I need to check that the surname is the same to the first name.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that the files are really supposed to be **identical**, right down to text qualifiers, ordering of rows, and number of rows contained in each file, the simplest approach may be to simply iterate through both files together and compare each line.

```
using (StreamReader f1 = new StreamReader(path1))
using (StreamReader f2 = new StreamReader(path2)) {

    var differences = new List<string>();

    int lineNumber = 0;

    while (!f1.EndOfStream) {
        if (f2.EndOfStream) {
           differences.Add("Differing number of lines - f2 has less.");
           break;
        }

        lineNumber++;
        var line1 = f1.ReadLine();
        var line2 = f2.ReadLine();

        if (line1 != line2) {
           differences.Add(string.Format("Line {0} differs. File 1: {1}, File 2: {2}", lineNumber, line1, line2);
        }
    }

    if (!f2.EndOfStream) {
         differences.Add("Differing number of lines - f1 has less.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but just added a bit more detail, therefore this won't work.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hopefully either the files aren't too large or your laptop (or server) has tons of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your answers to the comments on your question, if it doesn't really need to be done with code, you could do worse than download a compare tool, which is likely to more sophisticated.

([Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) for example)

Answer (score 0):

OK, for anyone else that googles this and finds this. Here is what my answer was.

I exported the details to a CSV and ordered them numerically when they were exported for ease of use. Once they were exported as two CSV files, I then used a program called `Beyond Compare` which can be found [here](http://www.scootersoftware.com/). This allows the files to be compared.

At first I used Beyond Compare manually to test what I was exporting was correct etc, however Beyond Compare does have the ability to be able to use command lines to compare. This then results in everything done programatically, all that has to be done is a user views the results in `Beyond Compare`. You may be able to export them to another CSV, I havn't looked as the GUI of `Beyond Compare` is very nice and useful, so it is easier to use this.