# Best way to compare two CSV files using c#?

Tags: c#, csv

I am looking to compare two CSV files cell per cell.
Question:  How can I accomplish this assuming that the 3 csv files already exist on the drive. Would this method be an ideal way of presenting comparison results onto a third csv file?

For example:

```
Sheet1
        A       B       C       D
    1   Ann     300     700     1000    

    2   Zoe     2       4       6   

    3   Ian     100     200     300 

    4   Zak     90      90      180

Sheet2  
        A       B       C       D
    1   Ann     400     700     1100    

    2   Zoe     2       4       6   

    3   Ian     100     100     200 

    4   Zen     90      90      180

Results
        A       B       C       D
    1   O       X       O       X   

    2   O       O       O       O   

    3   O       O       X       X

    4   X       O       O       O
```

Comment: You're not looking for "the best way", but "any way that works", right? What have you tried? What is good or bad about your proposal, what question are you actually trying to get answered?

Comment: Try looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240218/efficiently-identify-changed-fields-in-csv-files-using-c-sharp) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458355/c-sharp-comparing-two-csv-files-and-giving-an-output)

Comment: For file #1 there are rows of user data (row1 = first name, last name, social security, row2 - first name, last name, social). For file #2 there is similar data arranged in a same way and my goal is to check if everything in file#1 row1 matches that of file#2 row.

Answer (score 2):

I think best way is to read into a DataTable and ten compare DataTables.  There are plenty of examples of comparing two  datatables on the web.  Use code below to read csv into a datatable

```
    public class CSVReader
    {

        public DataSet ReadCSVFile(string fullPath, bool headerRow)
        {

            string path = fullPath.Substring(0, fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            string filename = fullPath.Substring(fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    string ConStr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}" + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR={1};FMT=Delimited\\\"", path, headerRow ? "Yes" : "No");
                    string SQL = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", filename);
                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, ConStr);
                    adapter.Fill(ds, "TextFile");
                    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table1";
                }
                foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables["Table1"].Columns)
                {
                    col.ColumnName = col.ColumnName.Replace(" ", "_");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return ds;
        }
    }
​
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/).  Define your classes like this:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class data {
  public string A;
  public int B;
  public int C;
  public int D;
}
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class resultdata {
  public string A {get;set;}
  public string B {get;set;}
  public string C {get;set;}
  public string D {get;set;}
}
```

Then your code becomes:

```
var engine=new FileHelperEngine<data>();
var r1=engine.ReadFile("1.csv");
var r2=engine.ReadFile("2.csv");
var r3=r1.zip(r2,(f1,f2)=>new resultdata{
  A=f1.A==f2.A?"X":"O",
  B=f1.B==f2.B?"X":"O",
  C=f1.C==f2.C?"X":"O",
  D=f1.D==f2.D?"X":"O"});
var engine2=new FileHelperEngine<resultdata>();
engine2.WriteFile("3.csv",r3);
```

If you need to do very very large files (that you can't process in memory), you can use FileHelpers' Async methods and work on them line by line.